# About the mean-teacher algorithm, in the end we should use the student or the teacher model?

Tags: neural-networks, semi-supervised-learning

It may sound silly, but I didn't find an official approach about which final model I should choose when the mean-teacher training ends, even on the original [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.01780).

I know both will have very similar weights, as the model teacher weights are the EMA of the model student's weights. Anyhow, is there a formal decision about it? Which one I should keep to evaluate a testset?